# Is there any sample or good guide to understand the Anugilla API?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to get the "revisor" and "checkout user" of the Component or Page using the Anguilla API.

I dont find any good sample or guide in the live documentation. is there any other docs to understand the Anguilla API?

```
var itemuri = selection.getItem(0);
var obj = $models.getItem(itemuri);
```

Comment: You can download the API doc from sdltridionworld.com (login required)

Comment: Ram: I can download the API, but am looking for some examples :-)

Comment: On your initial question: there are some really good tutorials out there. Did you do a search for "Tridion GUI extension"? You are clearly making a start already: so what are you trying to accomplish with that code fragment and where are you stuck?

Comment: On finding some examples: have a look inside the `%TRIDION_HOME%\Web\WebUI` directory. It is full of code that does the most amazing things with the framework.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```js
var tcmUri = "";

$display.staticLoadItem(tcmUri, function(success)
{
    if(success)
    {
        var item = $models.getItem(tcmUri);
        var user = item.getInfo().LockedBy;

        $display.staticLoadItem(user.getId(), function(success2)
        {
            if(success2)
            {
                console.log(user.getInfo().FullName);
             }
        });
    }
});
```